# WCF Service instance not showing in perfmon

Tags: .net, wcf, performancecounter

I have a self-hosted WCF service and I'm trying to enable performance counters, so I have added this to the web.config file :

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <diagnostics performanceCounters="All" />
  ...
```

After running my service and making sure that it is running, I then open perfmon.exe and try to add the performance counters. However there's nothing shown in the "Instances of selected object" box.

my app.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging" switchValue="Warning, ActivityTracing">
        <listeners>
          <add type="System.Diagnostics.DefaultTraceListener" name="Default">
            <filter type="" />
          </add>
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
  </system.diagnostics>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
  </startup>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <diagnostics wmiProviderEnabled="true" performanceCounters="All">
      <messageLogging logMalformedMessages="false" logMessagesAtServiceLevel="false"
        logMessagesAtTransportLevel="false" />
    </diagnostics>
    <bindings>
      <ws2007HttpBinding>
        <binding name="soapBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="1073741824">
          <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="1073741824" maxArrayLength="1073741824" />
          <security mode="Message">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None" realm=""/>
            <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </ws2007HttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="defaultBehavior" name="SoapService">
        <endpoint address="http://localhost/SoapService/"
          binding="ws2007HttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="soapBinding" name=""
          contract="ISoapService" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost/SoapService/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="defaultBehavior">
          <serviceAuthorization impersonateCallerForAllOperations="false" />
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Why does perfmon not show up any instances running?

btw, if the app.config doesn't highlight for you running .NET v4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know if it is still valid but let me try an answer.

There are many things you should check :

- You are targetting .net 4. Some counters will be in ServiceModelXXX 4.0.0.0.
- Sometimes, you need to reinstall WCF counter. Visit this [post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/wcf/thread/5cdeaefb-2c96-41e9-bf81-e92621601370) for the command line.
- Counters Instances do not exist until there is a first call (if not using appfabric autostart)
- Your account should have the require permission : Performance Monitor/Log User